# Which c/c++ model animation library for OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++, models, c

I'm fairly new to game development, played around with xna before and just learning OpenGL & c now and I'm interested to know which c/c++ based model animation libraries are out there and which you would recommend? I don't have any particular model format in mind yet but probably a format that is supported by a free modelling tool like Blender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [Open Asset Import Library](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/), see if it has the features you are looking for. There is also [Animaded](http://animadead.sourceforge.net/) for skeletal animation but it's not been updated in a while

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that existed! Cool.